# JSF Error de validación: el valor no es válido

Tags: jsf, validación

Estoy desarrollando una app con jsf para la gestion de citas medicas y tengo un problema al momento de querer registrar una nueva cita. Ya que dependiendo el doctor traigo los horarios en los que atiende en un <h:selectOneMenu>... esto lo hago con ajax
Mi problema radica en el momento que quiero enviar el formulario al managed bean ya que antes de enviarse la información me dice que el campo de hora no es valido y no me permite el envio.

**AJAX QUE ME TRAE LOS HORARIOS...**

```
<h:selectOneMenu>
 <f:selectItems value="#{appointmentRequest.doctorList}" 
    var="doctor" itemLabel="#{doctor.nombres}" itemValue="#{doctor.idmedicos}">
</f:selectItems>
 <f:ajax render="hora" listener="#{appointmentRequest.showSchedule()}" event="change"></f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**RENDERIZADO DE LOS HORARIOS SEGUN EL MEDICO**

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="hora" value="#{appointmentRequest.appointment.horaCita}">
 <f:selectItems value="#{appointmentRequest.scheduleDoctor}" var="h" itemLabel="#{h}"  itemValue="#{h}"></f:selectItems>
 <h:message for="hora"></h:message>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

**METODO DEL MANAGED BEAN QUE ME FORMA LA LISTA DE HORARIOS SEGUN EL MEDICO**

```
public void showSchedule(){
  Medicos doctor = medicosFacadeLocal.find(idDoctor);
  Integer beginHour = Integer.parseInt(doctor.getHoraInicioAtencion());
  Integer endHour = Integer.parseInt(doctor.getHoraFinAtencion());
  for(int i = beginHour;i <= endHour;i++){
            scheduleDoctor.add(String.valueOf(i));
  }
}
```

**TIPO DE DATO DONDE QUIERO ALMACENAR EL VALOR**

```
private String horaCita;
```

La verdad es que no encuentro por que al querer enviar el valor al managed bean me dice que el tipo de dato no es valido si el lugar donde quiero guardar el dato es de tipo String. No se si debo realizar alguna validación adicional.
Agradezco muchisimo a la persona que me pueda colaborar.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas el `c:forEach` en vez de un `f:selectItems`? Mezclar JSTL y JSF puede ser complicado, y en este caso parece innecesario. Además, no informas del tipo que tiene `appointmentRequest.scheduleDoctor`

Comment: como estas. Bueno mira la verdad es que soy nuevo en jsf sin embargo tome en cuenta tu sugerencia de utilizar unicamente **f:selectItems** pero el problema aún persiste. Por otra parte la lista  **appointmentRequest.scheduleDoctor** es un **ArrayList<String>** @SJuan76

Answer (score 1):

Bueno despues de tanto investigar y gracias a esta respuesta
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9069379/validation-error-value-is-not-valid/9069660#9069660
puede dar con la solución.
y el problema radica principalmente en que al momento de querer enviar de nuevo el formulario. JSF valida que la lista inicial desde la que se renderizo el <f:selectItems aún exista en el managed bean por ende lo que soluciono mi problema fue dar un alcance @ViewScoped al managed bean.